# How can I make a user-selected theme apply on all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website project, and I need a way for a user to select the theme to be light or dark. Ideally I would like the light and dark themes to be stored in different css files, and actuated by a button. I also need the styles to be applied across all pages, and to change to the selected theme no matter what page the user is on.

Also is there any way to make this possible without using databases? I'm aiming to make this site a self-contained offline package, working off of localhost. Is this at all possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can store the set themes in localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage